# I have disappearing lines from my SSRS report

Tags: ssrs-2008, rdl

I have an SSRS report, the layout based on an Excel spreadsheet.  Therefore, I have a lot of drawn lines and rectangles to mimic what Excel would print.  I also have two images that are loaded from fields in the database, if they exist for the record.  If the images are displayed, I have several lines missing from the report.  If the database returns more than one page worth of data, the first page of the report will have all lines, but the rest will be missing those same 5 lines.

Has anyone run into a situation where drawing elements would simply disappear from a SSRS/RDL report?

Comment: My lines disappear if they are inside another visual element - i.e., rectangle, text box, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We simply removed all the text boxes and re-drew them.  Still don't know why we had the problem in the first place.